# How to return columns with unique counts per value in other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have a pandas dataframe containing names in 3 columns. Looking something like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| NameColumn1 | NameColumn2 | NameColumn3 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Name1       | Name2       | Name3       |
| Name1       | Name2       | Name6       |
| Name1       | Name2       | Name8       |
| Name1       | Name4       | Name5       |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Now I would like to add 3 new columns containing counts of the unique values per name in the column to the left of it.

So for example the first column I would like to add would be the count of unique names in Column2 per unique name in column 1. So that is 2 (Name2 and Name4) and add this to the dataframe.

For Column 3 and name in Column2 it would be 3 (name3, name6 and name8).

So for the example like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+--+
| NameCol1 | NameCol2 | NameCol3 | CountOfCol2 | CountOfCol3 |  |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+--+
| Name1    | Name2    | Name3    |           2 |           3 |  |
| Name1    | Name2    | Name6    |           2 |           3 |  |
| Name1    | Name2    | Name8    |           2 |           3 |  |
| Name1    | Name4    | Name5    |           2 |           1 |  |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+--+
```

Comment: Why not just show us the complete result that you want given this same input?  It isn't clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the answer for columns 2 and 3: count the unique pairs grouped by source against source,target pairs, broadcasting the result with the transform.

```
In [60]:df.groupby('NameColumn2')[['NameColumn2','NameColumn3']].transform(lambda x: x.nunique())['NameColumn3']
Out[60]: 
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    1
Name: NameColumn3, dtype: int64
```

Replace 2 by x and 3 by y in the formula above to get result of countofColy for unique pairs of columnx, columny